Authentication with Bot Framework Emulator v.4.14.1
I am trying to test the authentication with the Bot Emulator, right now I am using the the sample BotAuthenticationMSGraph in dotnet core.
I created an App Registration Single tenant and configured everything in the Bot Service.  When I test the connection everything work.
I deployed the code in Azure and I can sign in without any problem.

But I cannot make it works in the Bot Framework Emulator, I suspect I need to start ngrok, when I start the application I have a 400 error.
Any doc that show the step how to test Authentication with Entra ID with the emulator ?
Thanks

You won't be able to test a Single Tenant bot using Emulator. Please see more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Ccsharp#plan-your-deployment
